# Haddock - link to function in external module (whole module imported)

Tags: haskell, haddock

Suppose I have a Haskell module named `MyModule` that imports an **external** module like this:

```
import ModuleA hiding (a, b, c)
```

And I **cannot** modify this import statement, because the program is not exactly mine.

I wish to link to `ModuleA.external_function` in the documentation for `ModuleA`, in the comments above a function called `my_function`. So the code looks something like this:

```
-- | my_function makes use of 'ModuleA.external_function'
my_function :: Int -> Int
```

Using haddock 2.10.0, and running `cabal haddock`, the link to `ModuleA.external_function` is generated as `dist/doc/html/MyModule/ModuleA.html#v:external_function` . However, the problem is that the `dist/doc/html/MyModule/ModuleA.html` file does not exist.

How can I generate a link to the docs for `ModuleA` instead, like `module-A-package/docs/ModuleA.html#v:external_function`. In other words, something similar to what http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.2.0/docs/Data-Text.html has for its links to the `String` type (they link to http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.0.0/docs/Data-String.html#t:String)? Bear in mind that I **cannot** modify the `import` statement.

Thank you.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. In any case, if you have `ModuleA.someFunction` in scope then `'ModuleA.someFunction'` should work just fine. Looking at your generated path, it seems that `ModuleA` is in its own directory and in fact you're probably not exporting it. If it's not being exported, Haddock won't generate documentation for it. Not all is lost with that case as you can pass `--ignore-all-exports` to Haddock. When using `cabal haddock`, you can use `--haddock-options` to pass it in. Alternatively, put `{-# OPTIONS_HADDOCK ignore-exports #-}` in `MyModule` and see if that does it.

Answer (score 1):

To make links to external packages in the Haddock documentation, you need to **instruct it where to find the documentation** for those packages.

It is done by using the `--read-interface` Haddock command-line option.

Using your example, it will be :

```
haddock --read-interface module-A-package/docs/,module-A-package/docs/module-A-package.haddock
```

The **.haddock** file is made when generating documentation for the package **module-A-package** using `----dump-interface` Haddock command-line option.

More information can be found on [the Haddock documentation](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/doc/html/invoking.html) or [this HaskellWiki page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haddock/FAQ).